# I have this error tring to get items in a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAqpq.png)

any one could help?

I am trying to get items in a list and subtract to get the items in the list that had been added in the last week only.

Comment: an you include as code-snippet, [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert iterable to list by add `.toList()` at end.

```dart
return userList.where(....).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a `List<Trans>` but you are currently returning an `Iterable<Trans>`

The easiest way to convert your `Iterable` into a `List` is to use a [`.toList()`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.8.0-dev.7.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) method on your `Iterable`.

```dart
return _userList.where((tx) {
 return tx.date.isAfter(DateTime.now().substract(Duration(days:7))):
}).toList();
```